# Excel: VLOOKUP & SUMIF

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a table, like so:

```
    TYPE       DEPARTMENT       HOURS
    DEV        DESIGN           3
               PROTO            7
               TRIM             2
    APPL       DESIGN           1
               TRIM             3
    R&D        DESIGN           10
```

What I want to do, is create a table for each department which works out the total amount of hours they spent on each 'TYPE'. For Instance:

```
DESIGN DEPARTMENT
    TYPE      HOURS
    DEV       3 
    APPL      1
    R&D       10
```

I was thinking of doing a VLOOKUP and combine it with a SUMIF but if I am not mistaken, VLOOKUP won't look through everything will it? It stops when it finds the first one.

I am open to trying this in VBA but it would be easier to use a formula. Do you guys have any suggestions? I don't need walking through it, just pointing in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `SUMPRODUCT` formula will solve what you want.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=F3)*(B2:B7=F1)*(C2:C7))
```

See this screenshot. Please amend the above formula for your scenario.

[image]

Comment: Siddharth Rout, what would be if we want to find something else except `DESIGN` , i.e. `PROTO`? There is a gaps in column A..

Comment: @simoco: OP wants to find the sum for only DESIGN as per his comment under bigtree's answer.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to how that works? Excuse my ignorance!

Comment: @Steve_M: No worries. I can explain it. Which part are you finding difficult to understand? If you press `F2` in Cell G3 you will see the dependent cells.

Comment: Just how it works really. It takes the SUM of all the types that equal F3, then multiplies that by the SUM of all the departments that equal F1 then multiplies that by the SUM of the total hours. I just don't see how it works

Comment: @Steve_M: `SUMPRODUCT` multiplies corresponding components in the given arrays, and returns the sum of those products. Here what we are trying to do is match 2 criterias and then finding sum for which the criteria meet.

Comment: @Steve_M:Did you try it in a blank worksheet to see if it works?

Comment: I will give it a go in a blank one - give me a few mins and I shall be back!

Comment: @Steve_M, can you explain what you have, please? You have one `A1:C7` table and many tables for each department like in `F1:G5` (see image in this answer) and you need to fill hours for each department?

Comment: @Steve_M: Similarly the formula in `G4` will be `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=F4)*(B2:B7=F1)*(C2:C7))` See how only F3 changes to F4 to incorporate the next `Type`

Comment: @SiddharthRout - That worked nicely! What an interesting formula. I've never thought about using formulas like that! I shall try it on my proper sheet! Thanks!

Comment: @SiddharthRout Would there be any issues with the data being on a different sheet as it is not seem to be liking it currently

Comment: @Steve_M: Glad you like it. However as simoco correctly mentioned, this formula will not work for `DEV+PROTO` as there is nothing next to `PROTO`. IF you fill `A3` with `DEV` then the above formula will definitely work.

Comment: @Steve_M: It shouldn't create any problem. Your formula should look something like this `=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet3!A2:A7=A3)*(Sheet3!B2:B7=A1)*(Sheet3!C2:C7))`

Comment: @Steve_M: If you upload your workbook to say www.wikisend.com and then share it here, then I can have a look?

Comment: Bare with me and I shall strip some data out as some of it is sensitive. Thanks very much for your help. Seriously.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46706/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-steve-m)

Answer (score 0):

Fill the gaps in your Type column [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436835/filling-any-empty-cells-with-the-value-above/20437063#20437063) then use a PivotTable with `DEPARTMENT` for Report Filter, `TYPE` for Row Labels and Sum of HOURS for Σ Values.

Comment: Sadly, I am unable to change this. It looks better with the gaps but is a royal pain!