# Excel - how to look in a dynamically changing range of multiple rows and columns and retrieve data

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I have 2 excel files. 1 is a workfile in which I work, the other is the output of a database. See pic 1 for my database output (simplified).

[image: Picture 1]

**What we see here:**

1. The purchase order numer in `column A`
2. The row in the database in `column B`
3. The status of the row in the database in `column C`
4. The classification in `column D`, where `W` means a product we want to measure and `P` meaning delivery costs, administration costs etc (we don't want to measure this)
5. The number of items ordered and the number of items delivered in `column E`
6. The company name and product info in `column F`

**Now, what I want, is something like this:**

[image: picture 2]

I want this table to be filled automatically based on the database output. It works for column B, but I'm stuck on **`column C, D and E`**.

---

## **What I want from you!**

I need help with column C, D and E.

**Number of rows:** it needs to calculate the rows **only** with **W** in `column D`. So for item `4410027708` it has to be `2` (only 2 rows with **W**) and for item `4410027709` it should be `1`.

**Items ordered:** it needs to **add-up** all the values that are directly to the right of the **W** in column D. So, for `4410027708`, it needs to add up `3` and `5`. It must ignore all the rows with **P**!

**Items to be delivered:** You may already guess this, but it needs to **add up** all the values in column `E` that are on the same row as column `C` with `To be delivered`, but **only** for the **W** rows (not the P versions). So, for item `4410027708` this should be

Comment: Where are you stuck with your code exactly? In SO we are not code providers but we would love to help you after you give us something to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest easy if ColumnA can be [filled down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20437063/1505120) first (including for the last entry) then assuming the database output sheet is called Sheet1, in:

C2:  `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!D:D,"W")`
D2:  `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!D:D,"W")`
E2:  `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!C:C,"To be delivered")`

copied down to suit.