# SQL Server : stretch values to emptly cells

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have problem with my table which look like this:

TABLE_XY

```
Dog
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
cat
NULL
NULL
NULL
Frog
..
```

I need from my table

```
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
cat
cat
cat
cat
cat
frog
frog
…
```

Do you know script which will stretch values to empty cells work my same like in excel. I cannot do manually because I have  over 1 million rows..

My opinion is > UPDATE column name when exist value extend down to next..

Thank for help

Comment: With no PK, this trivial problem becomes immensely problematic

Comment: Is this in Excel?  Why the Excel tag?

Comment: Is in Excel but i did not find correct MS manual for excel.

Comment: How do you define the ordering?

Comment: in Excel see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436835/filling-any-empty-cells-with-the-value-above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filling any empty cells with the value above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436835/filling-any-empty-cells-with-the-value-above)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column that specifies each row, you can do this using `apply`:

```
update t
   set t.col = tt.col
   from yourtable t cross apply
        (select top 1 t2.*
         from yourtable t2
         where t2.id < t.id and t2.col is not null
         order by t2.id desc
        ) tt
    where t.col is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column to order these results by

```
with CTE as
(
select Column1, row_number() over (order by OrderingColumn) as rn
from TableXYZ
)
select coalesce (x1.Column1, x2.Column1) as Column1
from CTE x1
left join CTE x2
on x2.rn = x1.rn+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column (let's say `id`) for ordering, you can execute the following query:

```
UPDATE table t
SET t.value = (
   SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = (
     SELECT MAX(id) FROM table WHERE id <= t.id AND value IS NOT NULL
    ) 
)
WHERE t.value IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will work, but the only caveat is that it might take a while to process all the million rows

```
   declare @tempTable table
(
Animal varchar(100)
)

insert into @tempTable
(Animal)
values
('Dog'),
(NULL),
(NULL),
('Cow'),
(NULL),
(NULL),
(NULL),
('cat'),
(NULL),
('Sheep'),
(NULL),
('Frog'),
(null),
('Buffalo')

declare @animal varchar(100)
declare @notNullAnimal varchar(100)

declare animalCursor cursor for
select animal
from @tempTable

open animalCursor

while (1=1)
begin

fetch next from animalCursor into @animal


if(@animal is not null)
begin
    set @notNullAnimal = @animal
end
else
begin
    if(@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0) break;

    update @tempTable
    set Animal = @notNullAnimal
    where current of animalCursor
end


if(@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0) break;


end

close animalCursor
deallocate animalCursor

select * from @tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a SSIS solution for this problem which is part of the SQL Server family.

It's pretty easy.

[image: Data Flow]

I used a SQL Statement to generate your sample and you can see it as animal in the data viewer.

The work is done in a very short script component. Code below (Note the setup of variable outside of the ProcessInputRow):
[image: c# script]

Comment: Based on above comments, it seems as if you are going from Excel to SQL Server. I'd recommend using this solution for your load.