# Index-Match formula to return the first non-blank match

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an index match formula to apply to in the following scenario:

```
 1  Column A       Column B        Column C
 2   Duck                           123ABC 
 3   Goose           .5             123ABC
 4   Duck                           456DEF
 5   Duck                           456DEF
 6   Goose           .9             456DEF
```

The formula formula will be placed in Column B only on blank lines by a VBA Macro.  I am working from the following formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$6),MATCH(C2,$C$2:$C:6,0))
```

The idea is that the resulting data set would appear as below:

```
 1  Column A       Column B        Column C
 2   Duck            .5             123ABC 
 3   Goose           .5             123ABC
 4   Duck            .9             456DEF
 5   Duck            .9             456DEF
 6   Goose           .9             456DEF
```

In order to achieve this I can see two possible options:

1. Have criteria in the formula to not return a value if the lookup finds a "blank" cell to return.  It would need to continue looking until it finds a value (a number).
2. Have a criteria that is part of the lookup which only returns a match if Column A says "Goose" (It will always be the case that the row that has a value has "Goose" in Column A.

I have researched online but can't find a method that works.

Comment: sort your data on column C and follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436835/filling-any-empty-cells-with-the-value-above except point to the cell below.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Unfortunately sorting the data is not an option in the application this will be used (Looking at multiple years of data that needs to stay in the row order it was originally added.

Answer (score 0):

I was able figure this out on my own.  The following array formula does what I was describing above:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$CB$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(($C$1:$C$6=C2)*($B$1:$B$6<>""),0),0))
```