# Loop that replicate my formula until last cell of my row

Tags: excel, vba

My aim is to have a formula that fills the empty cells with the previous Q. question, until the last non empty cell (see picture)
[image: picture]
The range is the last non empty cell of my row.

For now my code looks like this :

```
Sub Range_End_Exemple()
    
    Dim cell_target As Range
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+IF(ISBLANK(R[-2]C)=TRUE,RC[-1],R[-2]C)"
    
    Set cell_target = Worksheets("dataset Feedback forms").Range(Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select Type:xlFillDefault
    
End Sub
```

Thanks for you help if you have any suggestion.

Comment: I guess you tried to apply `AutoFill` with no luck, am I right?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: Yes exactly @Vitalizzare !

Comment: i don't know how i can make my code work ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filling any empty cells with the value above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436835/filling-any-empty-cells-with-the-value-above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub below is only based the picture you attached.

```
Sub test()
Dim LastCol As Range
Dim rg As Range
Dim cell As Range

With ActiveSheet
Set LastCol = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(-1, 0)
Set rg = .Range("D1", LastCol)
    For Each cell In rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.End(xlToRight).Column = .Columns.Count Then
            Range(cell, LastCol).Value = cell.Value
        Else
            Range(cell, cell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)).Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

The code assumed that nothing is change in "header-2".
The "header-1" will start in cell D1.
How many "type of header-1" is unknown.
The last column used in "header-2" is unknown.

The process:
it get the cell of the last column used in "header-2" then offset the row to -1 then have it as the LastCol variable. The LastCol cell is used to mark the end of "header-1".

then it get the range of the "header-1" into rg variable.

then it loop the cells of the rg which has value,
copy the cell till the last empty cells to the right (before the next header type of "header-1").

since the last header type of "header-1" will have no border, then it will check if the last empty cell column to the right value = the worksheet columns count ... then it use the LastCol variable as the border.

[image]

Based on seeing your image attachment, the thing which I'm unable to understand on what you want is : you use a formula for your "header-1" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot it is exactly the code i was trying to achieve ! :)
My only little issue is, your code is working when i try it on data without "Q. blabla", but not wih. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean in _"when I try it on data without Q. blablabla". In my gif animation header-1, the bla, bli, blu = whatever text. In your case : the orange "bla" = "Q. Applicant's Details:" .... the blue "bli" = "Q. Responsible For:" ... the green "blu" = "whatever" (if any).

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you appear to want from your image:

```
Sub Propagate()
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    With Worksheets("dataset Feedback forms")
        lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With .Cells(1, 4).Resize(1, lastCol - (4 - 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
            .Value2 = .Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! the fact is, i will not know the exact range between my values, nor the exact range of the last cell. That's the issue using this kind of formula :/

Comment: I suppose the last cell in row 1 isn't relevant (since you want to copy values to the right) - according to your image, the last cell would be the last non-empty cell in row 2, but mapped to row 1?

Comment: I've edited my answer based on my understanding as per my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

so I'd imagine something like this:

```
lrow = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False).Column ' <-- this gives you the last column blank

nextblank = Cells.Find("", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlByColumns, xlNext, False).Column ' <-- this gives you the FIRST blank column number

ltr = Split(Cells(1, nextblank - 1).Address, "$")(1) ' <-- this gives you the letter

aux = Range(ltr & "1") ' <-- this is the value you need to copy
```

After the first nextblank statement you need to use this to iterate

```
nextblank = Cells.Find("", Cells(1, nextblank), xlFormulas, xlByColumns, xlNext, False).Column
```

Using those values -> lrow doesn't change, it's your final destination

nextblank,ltr and aux values changes after you copy

Hope it helps!