# VBA code to ctrl arrow down to break in data, copy the last line before the break, paste to the blank line, and repeat until end of list

Tags: excel, vba, list, loops

I'm getting back into working with VBA after a few years away from it...

I have a report that I receive that has wrapped text and merged cells for presentation purposes. However, I'd like to unmerge the merged cells to be able to work the individual lines. I can do this pretty simply by recording a macro where I select everything and unwrap/unmerge all the data (although this does make for some lengthy code, so any tips to shorten that would be appreciated, but not the main point of my question).

Once unwrapped/unmerged, any of the rows that had merged cells now show two rows, the top one with the data that was merged, and the bottom row now blank, creating a break in the overall report. I want to write a macro that will basically control arrow down to the break in the data, copy the cell above the break, paste into the blank, and continue until the end of the report.

I've created a sample data file that illustrates what I'm looking at. The merge happens essentially because some projects have multiple elements (two managers or two cost centers), which makes sense for the formatted report, but not so much for doing any type of analysis on the overall data. The issues in my sample would be Projects 19, 27 and 37.

[image: Sample Data Image]

The real report I'm working with is much larger, so a macro would be nice to quickly achieve the formatting I'm after, instead of manually copy/pasting at each unmerged break in the data. This is probably extremely simple, but my basic google searches are opening more complicated doors than I want to open. I'd assume I'm looking for some sort of Do Until active cell = blank loop, but any and all solutions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance to any who can help with this.

I've tried searching the web for ways to create a loop that looks for a break in a list, but I'm overwhelmed by the results, most of which seem much more complicated than what I'm likely looking for. Remembered this site and that I'd asked a question here years ago and quickly received some helpful advice - figured I'd try that again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436835/filling-any-empty-cells-with-the-value-above

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and fastest way to do this would be Powerquery.

1. Convert the data to a table (Home > format as table) => this will remove all merged cells.
2. Click on the table and go to menu Data > From table/Range => this will open Powerquery.
3. Right click the column to fill and choose Fill > down
4. Go to the Home menu and choose "Close & load"

Your normalized table will be loaded to a new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will loop over all cells (of the active worksheet).

If will check if the cell is part of merged cells (`mergeArea.Count > 1`). If yes, it will unmerge it and write the content of that cell into the cells that where part of the merged area and *below* the cell.

```
Sub UnMerge()
    Dim cell As Range
    ' Change the following line if you don't want to work on the Active Sheet
    ' or if you don't want to process the complete "UsedRange",
    ' eg: For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H123")
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange 
        If cell.mergeArea.Count > 0 Then          ' Cell is the first cell of a merged Area.
            Dim mergeArea As Range, row As Long
            Set mergeArea = cell.mergeArea        ' Remember the mergeArea
            cell.UnMerge                          ' Unmerge cell
            ' Loop over all rows of the former merged area except first row
            For row = 2 To mergeArea.Rows.Count  
                mergeArea(row, 1).Value = mergeArea(1, 1).Value
            Next row
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Borders.LineStyle property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.borders.linestyle?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm181077)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet, c As Range
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    ' Get the last row#
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:B" & lastRow)
        ' Unmerge cells on the first 2 cols
         .UnMerge
         ' Get the blank cells
         Set c = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
         If Not c Is Nothing Then
            ' Fill down
             c.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
         End If
         ' Covert formulas to values
         .Formula = .Value
         ' Apply border line
         .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]