# Excel subtotal where the reference only shown once

Tags: excel, subtotal

does someone know How I can make the Excel to provide the subtotal based on the Company?

When I try the standard subtotal then it does not give me the right subtotal.

[image]

Comment: The regular `Subtotal` feature of Excel is not working because you have blanks in `Company` Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do to make the `SUBTOTAL` feature of Excel to work:

[image]

---

To use the `Subtotal` feature of `Excel` you cannot have blanks for the `Company` Column. You should have got an error message stating :

> Microsoft Excel cannot determine which row in your list or selection
> contains column labels, which are required for this command.
>
> - If you want the first row of the selection or list used as labels and not  as data, click 0K.
> - If you selected a subset of cells in error, select a single cell, and try the command again.
> - To create column labels, click Cancel, and enter a text label at the top of each column of data.
> - For information about creating labels that are easy to detect, click Help.

Not reinventing the process to fill down from above, you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20437063/8162520)<sup>*</sup> on how to do it and then use the `Subtotal` feature.

---

To outline the process, I did (Just in case one cannot follow .gif)

- Select the `Company` range till the last row --> hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>FD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open the `Go To Special` or can follow the answer<sup>*</sup>. Click `Blanks` --> enter <kbd>=</kbd> --> click <kbd>▲</kbd> and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> together.
- Value paste the range as well.
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> to select all the data
- Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to open `Subtotal` (will again get an error pop because there are blanks --> nevermind select `OK` and move ahead)
- Ensure --> `At each change in:` --> `Company` --> `Use Function:` --> `SUM` --> `Add Subtotal to:` --> Check `Value` --> select in below only `Value` --> Hit `OK` (Selections are as per one's preference and requirements).
- Now, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to apply filter. Select the `Invoice` Column and filter out blanks --> Select `Company` Col --> hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to select visible cells and press <kbd>DEL</kbd> from your keyboard --> remove filters to get what you need.

---

May be not elegant or neat, but you could achieve this using `Excel Formulas` assuming no `Excel Constraints` and using `MS365` then:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:D10,
     _Company, SCAN(,TAKE(_Data,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _Value, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _Sum, BYROW(_Company,LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=_Company)*_Value))),
     HSTACK(DROP(_Data,,-1),IF(_Value<>"",_Value,DROP(VSTACK("",_Sum),-1))))
```

---

- Using `LET()` function makes easier to read, eliminates redundant ranges, increases performance.
- `_Data` variable is the source range defined.
- `_Company` variable where `SCAN()` and `TAKE()` function is used. Using the `TAKE()` function grabbing the `Company` range. Next, using `SCAN()` filling all the blanks from above value. Here, the initial value is an empty string which is the **`[initial_value]`** while the one returned using `TAKE()` is the range which needs to be filled in, it uses a `LAMBDA()` helper function, where `x` is the **`[accumulator]`** and `y` is the current range. If the current cell is empty it uses `x` while if not empty then retains the `y`, keeps iterating until and unless its filled up.
- `_Value` variable is the `value` columns grabbed using `TAKE()` function.
- `_Sum` variable uses `BYROW()` function, which applies a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations to each row in the array and returns one output per row.
- Finally, in the last step, we are doing some logical test to return values when its `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively. `DROP()` function used twice, which drops the last cell from the array. While `HSTACK()` function is used to combine the arrays into one and stack horizontally, to return the final output.

---

**Note:** The `zeros` are hidden using `Custom formatting` --> `General;;`

---